# What would be the bound of integration for this triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I don't understand why theta and thy range from 0 to pi/2. shouldn't it be from 0 to pi/4 since you divide the whole sphere by 8? a full circle is 2pi, so eight of a circle should be pi/4. Down below is the question and the answer key

[image]

[image]

Comment: $Q$ is the eighth of the sphere, so you will cut it into 8 pieces, 4 up, and 4 down, and evaluate only one eighth. What angle gives you 4 identical pieces when cutting a circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not taking an eighth of the range of these angles—you're taking an eighth of the the sphere's volume. In order to get this, you need to take a quarter of the angle range for $\theta$ and half of the range for $\phi$.

In order to wrap your head around this, keep in mind the visual intuition behind $\theta$ and $\phi$ with spherical coordinates:
[image]

You are right, to a degree. The full range of $\theta$ is $0\leq\theta<2\pi$, which visually represents the unit circle on the xy-plane; the full range for $\phi$ is $0\leq\phi\leq\pi$, which visually represents half of the unit circle on the yz-plane.

Notice that if $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, you restrict the range of the sphere to the first quadrant of the xy-plane, which is a quarter of the entire xyz-plane. If you restrict $0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, you get only positive values for $z$, giving you an eighth of the xyz-plane.